# Inclusion-Exclusion Chocolate Bar Problem

Tags: probability, inclusion-exclusion

There are 15 chocolate bars and 10 children. In how many ways can the bars be distributed to the children in each of the following scenarios.

(c) The chocolate bars are not interchangeable (it matters which particular bar goes where)

(d) The chocolate bars are not interchangeable, and each child must receive at least one

I figured out the way if the chocolate bars are interchangeable, but how would I go about if the order matters?

Comment: I saw the same question yesterday and there is another one [number of possible ways to distribute 15 chocolate bars among 10 children](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1058952/number-of-possible-ways-to-distribute-15-chocolate-bars-among-10-children?s=1|1.1647)

Comment: I didn't see that one. I'll take a look at it. Thanks!